# Cannot clone private repo in which I am an admin even with SSH keys / OAUTH

Tags: github, permission-denied

I use GitKraken with OAUTH and work often with private repositories without issue. I was recently invited to a repo that is owned by an organization *and* is private. I am an admin on the repository. It appears forking is disabled but what is strange is when I try to clone it, I receive the following popup:

[image: Clone Failed]

It also doesn't show up in my list of available repositories though the rest of my private repos *do* appear. Trying to figure out if there is some odd organizational permission I need to get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to switch back (temporarily, for testing) to command-line and check what origin is:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

Make sure it is an SSH GitHub URL (`git@github.com:me/myRepo`)

You can test its access (even without cloning it) with:

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:me/myRepo
```